# Duplicating small file on remote Windows Server takes time

Tags: windows, vpn

I have a remote server which is in the Cloud. A am connected through a permanent VPN to it. I have a network share that points on this server (W2016).

If I duplicate (copy/paste) a file on this network share that is 2Mb. It will take arround 40 secondes to accomplish. I have 100mb Fibre.

Is is normal that it takes 40 secondes ? Isn't supposed to be fast as I copy/paste on the same drive (the remote servers drive) and not event from server to my PC ?

When I copy/paste on this remote server, is the data passing through my PC as I am the on that initiated the c/p ?

Comment: Copy and Paste **on the same share** with a sufficiently recent Windows version should, as far as I know, be a *"server side copy"*  and not first download the file to your PC before the copy will be uploaded again to the new location, but if you have for instance anti-virus that performs an on-access scan ...

Comment: Either way, that's not normal.  Perhaps the cloud service needs that long to spin the server up?  If you copy another file immediately after the first one does it still take that long?  (For what it's worth, that's roughly the same amount of time it takes a physical Windows machine to wake from sleep in response to network activity.  So if it is actually a physical machine rather than a virtual one, perhaps it was sleeping?)

Answer (score -1):

I understood why it is slow.
Basically the copy/paste operation IS server-side.
But my computer reads the entire file on the remote share before copying it.
So if the file is 40Mb for example, well my PC has to read 40Mb in any case.
So it is kind of downloading the file data and reuploading it but without storing it on my pc.

Comment: That's not a server side copy. A server side copy would mean the server understands the file should be copied to another location on the same server and does this *without* copying the file to your local machine beforehand.